# PHP Send method call as parameter for method

Tags: php

I have the following pattern of code in a lot of methods:

```
    $attempts = 0;

    do {

    $response = $this->DOSOMETHIING($data, $info);

    sleep(1);

    $attempts++;

    } while ($attempts < 5);
```

What I would like to do is have a helper method for this while loop that can somehow be sent a specific method call. So something like this:

```
$response = $this->execute($this->DOSOMETHIING($data, $info));
```

The helper method:

```
function execute($method){

$attempts = 0;

    do {

    $response = $method(); <<< I know!

    sleep(1);

    $attempts++;

    } while ($attempts < 5);

 return $response;

}
```

The trouble is that the method call being sent to the helper method will be one of 3 different method calls and they all have a different number of parameters, so it's not like I can send the method and the parameters separately.

Comment: Something like a [Callback / Callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)?

Comment: It doesn't look like parameters are included in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need closure pattern : http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

bellow code use same "execute" function for two kind of traitment :

```
public function __construct() {

}

public function execute($method) {
    $attempts = 0;
    do {
        $response = $method();
        sleep(1);
        $attempts++;
    } while ($attempts < 5);
    return $response;
}

public function foo($data, $info) {
    //Do something
    return array_merge($data,$info);
}

public function bar($other) {
    echo 'Hello '.$other;
}

public function main() {
    $data = ['foo' => 'bar'];
    $info = ['some' => 'info'];
    $other = 'world';

    $return = $this->execute(function() use ($data, $info) {
        return $this->foo($data,$info);
    });   
    var_dump($return);
    $this->execute(function() use ($other) {
        $this->bar($other);
    });
}
}

$tester = new Foo();
$tester->main();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) which will return the value of your callback.